# History of the functor of points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ho.history-overview, schemes, representable-functors

Until now, I thought the functor of points approach was introduced by Grothendieck at the 1973 Buffalo seminar.

However, in [this note by Lawvere](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.categories/2228) the author writes:

> "I myself had learned the functorial point of view from Gabriel in 1966 at the
>   Strasbourg-Heidelberg-Oberwolfach seminar and therefore I was
>   particularly gratified when I heard Grothendieck so emphatically
>   urging that it should replace the one previously expounded by
>   Dieudonne' and himself."

Lawvere also says this definition is "essentially well known".

I'm wondering when exactly this approach was introduced, and by whom. It seems like quintessential Grothendieck. What motivated this definition?

Comment: I thought Grothendieck was, at least partially, motivated by his experience in analysis, the Riesz theorem, etc  - you turn functions into functionals by integrating agains them - and then replace inner products by Hom's.

Comment: @PeterDalakov: I wonder, are there any sources to back up this (eminently plausible-sounding) claim?

Comment: Will the downvoter explain the downvote?

Comment: Surely, it was due to Grothendieck, but well before 1973. One can find functors of points for schemes (originally called preschemes) discussed in EGA I (chap I, sect 3.4), which was written in 1960.

Comment: What the 1973 Buffalo lecture is famous for is Grothendieck urging to drop the older definition of scheme in favor of the functor of points definition. In EGA I, 1960 IHES edition, you find discussion about the functor of points associated to a scheme. The 1971 Springer edition embraces the functor of points much more (though the definition of scheme given is still the locally ringed space one). That said, I agree that the definition must have been in the air much earlier.

Comment: In Seminaire Heidelberg-Strasbourg 1965-66, Groupes Algebriques, (Demazure, Gabriel et al.) a scheme is defined as in EGA, but then it is immediately shown that the category of schemes is equivalent to the category of functors on (small) rings satisfying certain conditions. In their book Groupes Algebriques 1970, Demazure and Gabriel define a scheme to be a functor satisfying certain conditions (p.12). As they say (p.xvi) "In this way, certain functors are schemes, instead of defining schemes up to a unique isomorphism, which is technically more advantageous".

Comment: Demazure-Gabriel (1970) may be the first (and only?) published book entirely defining schemes as functors. This point-of-view is particularly natural for group schemes.

Comment: Certainly  from the very start Grothendieck (and others) found it useful to often think of schemes as functors, but it may have been Demazure and Gabriel who first defined them as functors.

Comment: This question seems like a perfect fit for [hsm.se]. Would you consider a migration, Arrow?

Comment: @Danu I don't mind a migration.